# Error messages while implementing mergesort related to timeit and the index range

Tags: python

I need to implement mergesort in python and compare the execution time given a few lists of different lengths consisting of random numbers. More precisely, I have to find if the execution time is linear, quadratic or something else, by means of a plot. We know that mergesort has a running time of $O(NlogN).$ Unfortunately, I get error messages related to the execution time part but I also get the following:

```
File "/home/myname/file.py", line 58, in merge
    S[k] = S2[j]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Here is the code. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mergesort(S):
    n = S.size

    if n == 1:
        return S
    else:
        S1, S2 = split(S)
        S1sorted = mergesort(S1)
        S2sorted = mergesort(S2)
        Ssorted = merge(S1sorted, S2sorted)
        return Ssorted


def split(S):
    l = len(S)//2
    S1 = S[:l]
    S2 = S[l:]
    return S1, S2


def merge(S1, S2):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    S = []
    while i < len(S1) and j < len(S2):
         if S1[i] < S2[j]:
             S[k] = S1[i]
             i += 1
         else:
             S[k] = S2[j]
             j += 1
         k += 1
           
    while i < len(S1):
         S[k] = S1[i]
         i += 1
         k += 1  
    while j < len(S2):
         S[k] = S2[j]
         j += 1
         k += 1            
    return S

if __name__ == '__main__':
    random.seed(5)
    d = [np.random.rand(10**i) for i in range(10)]
    print("List of lists:\n",d)
    time_list = []
    length_list = []
    for s in d:
        execution_time = timeit.timeit(stmt = 'mergesort(s)', setup='from __main__ import mergesort,s')
        time_list.append(execution_time)
        length_list.append(len(s))
        print("The list s:\n", s)
        print("The execution time for the list",s,"is:\n", timeit.timeit(stmt = 'mergesort(s)', setup='from __main__ import mergesort,s'))

    plt.scatter(length_list, time_list)
    plt.xlabel("N")
    plt.ylabel("Execution time for a list of length N")
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

issue is in function `merge` you have define the size of list `S` to zero ie `S = []`

and in the below code you are setting the value for index `k`. means for empty array you are assigning values which shouldn't be.

All you need to do is make list `S` equal to `len(S1) +` len(S2)`.

so below is right code for `merge` function

```
def merge(S1, S2):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    S = [None for _ in range(len(S1)+len(S2))] # < -- change happen here
    while i < len(S1) and j < len(S2):
         if S1[i] < S2[j]:
             S[k] = S1[i]
             i += 1
         else:
             S[k] = S2[j]
             j += 1
         k += 1
           
    while i < len(S1):
         S[k] = S1[i]
         i += 1
         k += 1  
    while j < len(S2):
         S[k] = S2[j]
         j += 1
         k += 1            
    return S
```

EDIT:
what does `None` and `_` means below

`S = [None for _ in range(len(S1)+len(S2))]`

`_`  here it is just a throwaway variable, which is not assigned anywhere and not need, just used to make list comprehension

`None` used to Assign as default value to the final sorted list,when we are initalising/declaring the final list ie `S`

this is same as `S = [n] * None`

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the line where S occurs? What is meant by None and the underscore?

Comment: @user996159 added the explaination

Answer (score 1):

In that specific line `S[k] = S1[i]` you are trying to assign to the k-ish element of your list a value. However this element does not exist. Try using  S.append(S1[i]).